# What percentage of pet identification chips (i.e. Avid) are reassigned by new owners?

Tags: identification

This comes from a discussion on the question [What information should we leave for a cat sitter/cattery?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7478) The chip company has a record of who the "pet owner" contact is, this can be updated when the pet is transferred to a new owner.

My Question is what percentage of new owners transfer contact information when a chip was originally registered to a previous owner/organization?  I am particularly interested in the break out of shelter/rescue pets.

I know in our family all of our pets are rescued.  The shelters we adopt from have generally installed the chip and they are listed as the owner.  The shelter keeps a record of adopting the specific pet to us.  We have chosen not to update contact information for the chip.

1. If the pet is lost and we know it, we are actively searching in the local area, so there is little chance that contact through chip information would be required.
2. If we don't know the pet is lost or if we don't know what area the pet is in, there is little chance that our home contact information provides any benefit to whomever is reading the chip.

So worst case, our pet ends up back at the shelter we rescued them from.  Because we know this, our local rescues acts as an always available intermediary.

While I have a specific motivation for not updating, I doubt that motivation for updating or not is available.  But I am curious to learn what percentage of chips are updated on pet transfer.  Preferable with breakdown by original chip installer; rescue/shelter, breeder, personal vet, other.

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Doing some research... some registries allow for both you **and** the shelter to be listed. That seems to be a very ideal approach to be honest.

Comment: Also, it does require the organization to do the transfer if they have registered the chip. You can't do it without them from what I see.