# Pet sitting best practice

Tags: cats, safety

This is my first time hiring a pet sitter for my cat. I found her on Rover with good reviews. Is there anything I should be aware of, since I will be giving her my house keys? Should I get her ID just in case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things I would do, including:

1. Gather all of your important papers, good jewelry, and anything of true sentimental value.
2. Make sure information about your finances are not accessable. (bank
   accounts, credit cards, loan agreements, your lease or house
   payment, etc.)
3. Lock these items up (in a file cabinet, in a closet, in your (bank's) security deposit box) or leave them in the care of someone you trust (a parent, or sibling) to hold until you return.
4. Write down basic instructions for your cat's care. Feeding schedules, medicines, favorite treats, how many treats/day are allowed, favorite games/toys. Is your cat allowed in and out of the home? If not, what should the sitter do if the cat gets out? And your Vet's information and location in case of emergency.
5. Emergency number of a friend or neighbor in case they cannot reach you.
6. Rules of the house (no smoking, shoes come off at the door, etc.).
7. Anything else you can think of.

Essentially, you don't want to leave anything around that you would regret losing. You want to make sure that the sitter has all of the information they need to properly care for your cat. You want the sitter to have more than your number to call if there is an emergency. And you want to avoid lying awake in the middle of the night because you forgot something.
At that point, you should be able to relax and know that kitty will be just fine.
p.s. I am not suggesting that your pet sitter is going to steal from you. I am just saying that I would lock up important stuff (like my rings). Call me paranoid. Now go enjoy your vacation. :)

Comment: the name and phone number to your vet and where the carrier for the cat is,you can put the cats health card in the carrier if it should be needed.